# MongoDB: Aggregation using $cond with $regex

Tags: regex, mongodb, conditional-statements, aggregation-framework, grouping

I am trying to group data in multiple stages.

At the moment my query looks like this:

```
db.captions.aggregate([
{$project: {
    "videoId": "$videoId",
    "plainText": "$plainText",
    "Group1": {$cond: {if: {$eq: ["plainText", {"$regex": /leave\sa\scomment/i}]}, 
        then: "Yes", else: "No"}}}}
])
```

I am not sure whether it is actually possible to use the $regex operator within a $cond in the aggregation stage. I would appreciate your help very much!

Thanks in advance

Comment: `$regex` does not work inside `$cond`. Also see this one: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-11947 There's way around that, though.

Comment: Would `$substr` be sufficient for your case? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30221039/is-it-possible-to-write-regular-expression-in-cond-in-mongodb

Comment: @dnickless Thanks for the quick response and the clarification. That already helps a lot. What would you suggest as a work around for my case? I'd like to add a field ("CalltoAction") that tells me wheter the video has one or more of the defined keywords in its caption or not. Thanks

Comment: I dont think `substr` would be sufficient. The condition I'd like to create queries the whole caption of a video for multiple keywords or short sentences and tells me whether at least one the keywords I defined is included or not.

Comment: How about using `$indexOfBytes` one instead and comparing it to -1 with a bunch of `$or`s? https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfBytes/

Comment: I am not quite sure whether $indexOfBytes is suitable for my problem, since I have never used it before. But it displayed an error message, when trying to test it with the keyword "comment". I updated my question to show you.

Comment: Which MongoDB version are you using?

Comment: I am using version 3.2.12

Comment: That would explain why you cannot use this operator. ;) It simply didn't exist back then.

Comment: Oh okay:) I will try to update it to the latest version. So just to make sure I have a couple of questions 1. with version 3.2.12 there is no way to get the output I want? 2. Furthermore I am wondering what would be the best solution for my problem in the latest version. 3. If I am using the `$indexOfBytes` operator, what would the result be when I query a field for multiple keywords. Does it return the UTF-8 byte index of the first keyword and of the first occurence?

Comment: With 3.2 you could perhaps use $text (https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/query/text/#text-query-operator-behavior, https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/text-search-in-aggregation/) but that gives you little control. With 3.4 and up you could probably use $facet which won't give you supreme performance but at least it should work.

Comment: Okay thank you, I will look into $text for now. I have no experience with $facet either, but I will give it a try as soon as I have the latest MongoDB version. Would you mind giving me an example of $facet that matches my problem as a starting point? I am looking for a result like this `{"videoId" : "ErsncESnW_0", "CalltoAction": "yes"}`

Comment: Klar. Siehe unten. ;)

Comment: Perfekt, vielen herzlichen Dank für die Hilfe und "en schöne Abig";)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPDATE:** Starting with MongoDB v4.1.11, there finally appears to be a nice solution for your problem which is documented [here](http://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-11947).

---

**Original answer:**

As I wrote in the comments above, `$regex` does not work inside `$cond` as of now. There is an open [JIRA ticket](http://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-11947) for that but it's, err, well, open...

In your specific case, I would tend to suggest you solve that topic on the client side unless you're dealing with crazy amounts of input data of which you will always only return small subsets. Judging by your query it would appear like you are always going to retrieve all document just bucketed into two result groups ("Yes" and "No").

If you don't want or cannot solve that topic on the client side, then here is something that uses [$facet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/) (MongoDB >= v3.4 required) - it's neither particularly fast nor overly pretty but it might help you to get started.

```
db.captions.aggregate([{
    $facet: { // create two stages that will be processed using the full input data set from the "captions" collection
        "CallToActionYes": [{ // the first stage will...
            $match: { // only contain documents...
                "plainText": /leave\sa\scomment/i // that are allowed by the $regex filter (which could be extended with multiple $or expressions or changed to $in/$nin which accept regular expressions, too)
            }
        }, {
            $addFields: { // for all matching documents...
                "CallToAction": "Yes" // we create a new field called "CallsToAction" which will be set to "Yes"
            }
        }],
        "CallToActionNo": [{ // similar as above except we're doing the inverse filter using $not
            $match: {
                "plainText": { $not: /leave\sa\scomment/i }
            }
        }, {
            $addFields: {
                "CallToAction": "No" // and, of course, we set the field to "No"
            }
        }]
    }
}, {
    $project: { // we got two arrays of result documents out of the previous stage
        "allDocuments" : { $setUnion: [ "$CallToActionYes", "$CallToActionNo" ] } // so let's merge them into a single one called "allDocuments"
    }
}, {
    $unwind: "$allDocuments" // flatten the "allDocuments" result array
}, {
    $replaceRoot: { // restore the original document structure by moving everything inside "allDocuments" up to the top
        newRoot: "$allDocuments"
    }
}, {
    $project: { // include only the two relevant fields in the output (and the _id)
        "videoId": 1,
        "CallToAction": 1
    }
}])
```

As always with the aggregation framework, it may help to remove individual stages from the end of the pipeline and run the partial query in order to get an understanding of what each individual stage does.

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much! I will test it as soon as I will have updated my mongodb version but it seems to be exactly what I was looking for:) Concerning your assumptions above, yes I am always retrieving all documents in the captions collection. In the end the output should display the videoId, CalltoAction (yes or no) as well as other statistical data like the amount of views for example. I will add the statistical data to the query you proposed, which should give me desired result. Thanks again for your help as well as all the additional explanation in the query!

Comment: @dnickless, thank you for introducing me to $facet. This helped me simplify a big aggregation query

Comment: @ShabinMuhammed, you're welcome. Be careful with `$facet`, though, as it produces a single output document which can be very big - often you will find other ways to optimize complex queries without the use of `$facet`. Also, feel free to post a question on SO which explains the aggregation query that you just shortened - it may well be that it can be optimized further/differently.

Comment: @dnickless, I'm using it in an analytics aggregation. Last stage of pipeline is all $count, so it wont grow out of bound accidently. My use case was that I needed to get no.of hits on specific url patterns. But analytics collection contain many other events also. The group stage doesn't accept regex, so I had to do individual aggs for each pattern. With $facet, I'm able to do $match with regex after mapping page_hit events in the first stage of agg and further breaking down the results into sets of matching patterns in each field of $facet and counting them.