# Mongodb aggregation $or condition on $eq

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I want to increment the value of the field 'XR' on either getting the value of modality equals to XR or CR or DX. But unfortunately its somehow not working. I read somewhere that the $eq can take regex. So my question is, Is there any why by which i can make an or comparison within $cond and $eq.

```
    {
      $group: {
        _id: { week: { $week: '$createdAt' }, year: { $year: '$createdAt' } },
        XR: { $sum: { $cond: [{ $eq: ['$modality', /(XR|CR|DX)/g] }, 1, 0] } },
        CT: { $sum: { $cond: [{ $eq: ['$modality', 'CT'] }, 1, 0] } },
        MR: { $sum: { $cond: [{ $eq: ['$modality', 'MR'] }, 1, 0] } },
        MG: { $sum: { $cond: [{ $eq: ['$modality', /(NM|MM|MG)/g] }, 1, 0] } },
      },
    },
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB: Aggregation using $cond with $regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49658581/mongodb-aggregation-using-cond-with-regex)

Comment: Hey AlexisG, Uh, Well i just want to know if there is any other workaround to do the same stuff with without regex.

Comment: You can use $in instead of $eq, like `{ $eq: ['$modality', ['NM', 'MM', 'MG']] }`